# what is the proper use of the CMake "project" directive

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a large-ish codebase which builds several dozen libaries and several executables.

The codebase is broken down hierarchically and libraries are build at pretty much every level.

I've gone through and placed a CMakeLists.txt file at each directory to build each library.

In each CMakeLists.txt I have used the "project( xxx )" directive. This has defined for me PROJECT_NAME, PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR and PROJECT_BINARY_DIR variables which I make judicious use of.

However, one of the team is unhappy with this approach as he can't find any real world examples of anyone else having done this. He often cites the KitWare examples as not using this approach and therefore neither should we.

The alternative approach he is advocating is to set these variables up in each makefile which seems much like what "project" gives you.

I really can't see his point and am making little headway in convincing him otherwise. Can anyone shed any light on the downsides of using the project directive in this way.

I throw myself on your collective wisdom?

Comment: How do you use the `PROJECT_NAME`, `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` and `PROJECT_BINARY_DIR` variables? And are these libraries independent or are they just parts of a main library/application?

Comment: I use these variables inside macros which generate source code. I create a top level target called ${PROJECT_NAME}_SPDEF which other projects can depend on to force generation of these. I also use the _DIR variables to place the generated code in the appropriate location.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, it enables you to use `<projectName>_BINARY_DIR` and `<projectName>_SOURCE_DIR`, but that's not the main advantage. If you give CMake a project name then it will generate build targets for each of the sub-projects in their own directories. This means that whether you're using GNU Make, Eclipse CDT, XCode, or any of the other supported generators you can build sub-projects individually. For instance with GNU Make each sub-project has its own full build system from it's own directory.

You can access the current project name through `PROJECT_NAME`, and the root project name by `CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME`.

Edit: I've just realised the below will be standard CMake behaviour for any of its build targets whether they're projects or not. I'll keep it here for general information but it is not pertinent to the answer:

Assume I have a C++ library, and I can generate three binary executables; `Main` and `tests/test1`, and `examples/ex1`. I can either run make in the directory I called CMake from with the ALL target, run `make ex1`, or I can change directory to `examples/` and build the examples with `make` from that directory. This will build all of the dependent projects and libraries even if they're somewhere else in the directory structure but won't build `Main` or `tests/test1` or any libraries that they depend on that `examples/ex1` doesn't. If I then run make from the main directory, it won't rebuild any of the libraries that `examples/ex1` depends on unless their source has changed.

Comment: The ability to be able to "cd" to any level of the build hierarchy and do "make all" and have all artefacts build from this level down is a big win for me. Thanks.

Comment: @ScaryAardvark the ability to run different commands for different compilers and include different code with different operating systems automatically is really nice, plus it's very easy to do fairly advanced operations with a couple of lines of code. I compress assets with `zip` with CMake, which works fine on any platform/IDE/toolchain. It also makes it very easy to cross-compile for ARM etc. You should also check out CMake's built in test system, [CTest](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Testing_With_CTest). There are also CMake plugins for CI systems like Jenkins.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with this. One question I had was how does cmake handle different version of the same compiler... i.e. we have one section of our project tree which can only be compiled under sunstudio11 and the most of it needs sunstudio12. I think I'll raise another question regarding that, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If the libraries are truly independent projects then it makes sense to use the `project` command. However if they are not I would instead just add them as subdirectories in your root `CmakeLists.txt`. You can use the variables [CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#variable%3aCMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR) and [CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#variable%3aCMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR) if you need to know the directories that are currently being processed.

Comment: Is there a CMAKE_CURRENT_PROJECT. If there is then I can see your point, however if I have to use set() to create this variable (or something similar) then why not use "project" and have all the variables created for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good usage example of exactly this today: adding Doxygen documentation.

I use CMake (and Ninja) to build my personal C++ projects. I decided on a whim to add some Doxygen documentation to one of my pretty much complete but undocumented efforts. I also thought it would be neat to add it to the other projects as well just as soon as I work out how to make it as generic as possible.

To begin with, I generated a standard Doxygen template and renamed it.

```
cd my_projects/projectx
doxygen -g Doxyfile
mv Doxyfile Doxyfile.in
```

Note the .in extension. Probably not necessary but conventional, if I understand correctly.

Next, I added  the following code block in my CMakeLists.txt file, just before defining my targets (not sure if that's important but CMake is sometimes fussy about the sequence of certain commands).

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Doxygen)
IF("${DOXYGEN_FOUND}" MATCHES "^YES$")
    CONFIGURE_FILE( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile.in
                    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile
                    @ONLY)
    ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(  doc ALL
                        COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE}
                        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile
                        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
                        COMMENT "Doxygenating..."
                        VERBATIM)
ENDIF()
```

This creates a new target called doc. Specifying ALL adds it to the default "all" target, but that's optional. Specifying @ONLY ensures that any "${variable}" type variables will not be expanded by CONFIGURE_FILE, only "@variable@" types. Somewhat confusingly (to me at least), CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR appears to refer to the project directory and CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR to the build directory.

Finally, and this is where PROJECT_NAME et al come in, I edited Doxyfile.in.

This is the beginning of my new Doxyfile.in:

```
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME           = "@PROJECT_NAME@"
PROJECT_NUMBER         = @PROJECT_VERSION_TWEAK@
PROJECT_BRIEF          =
PROJECT_LOGO           = @CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR@/res/doc_logo-200x55.png
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = @CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR@/doc
```

You get the idea, I think. Once this is fully genericised (is that a word?) I can copy it to my other projects and as long as I tag up my code, I will have nice documentation everywhere.

Notice PROJECT_BRIEF isn't specified. I haven't finished with this and there still a few blanks for me to think about. For instance PROJECT_VERSION_TWEAK doesn't actually contain anything yet. I will have to find a way to get my build number in there.